# ERROR: Could not find method repository() when using OneDrive SDK

Tags: android, gradle, onedrive

I'm trying to use the OneDrive SDK by following the instructions shown [here](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android#11-install-aar-via-gradle).  Unfortunately I can't perform a Gradle project sync when I add the dependencies shown in the SDK installation guide.  I get the following error message:

`ERROR: Could not find method repository() for arguments [build_xqhe0znpcz2uhmxa019kwrtr$_run_closure2@18623fec] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Please can someone help me identify the problem?  My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.onedrivesdkapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repository {
    jcenter()
}

dependency {
    // Include the sdk as a dependency
    compile ('com.onedrive.sdk:onedrive-sdk-android:1.3+') {
        transitive = false
    }

    // Include the gson dependency
    compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1')

    // Include supported authentication methods for your application
    compile ('com.microsoft.services.msa:msa-auth:0.8.+')
    compile ('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.1.+')
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [onedrive-sdk-android](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android) library is no longer maintained because the latest commit is 2 years ago.

**Problem:** Your code to import dependencies is not correct, that why Gradle throws the error.

**Solution:** Do the following steps.

**Step 1:** Remove the following line from gradle file

```
repository {
    jcenter()
}

dependency {
    // Include the sdk as a dependency
    compile ('com.onedrive.sdk:onedrive-sdk-android:1.3+') {
        transitive = false
    }

    // Include the gson dependency
    compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1')

    // Include supported authentication methods for your application
    compile ('com.microsoft.services.msa:msa-auth:0.8.+')
    compile ('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.1.+')
}
```

**Step 2:** Move all dependencies line to `dependencies` block.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Include the sdk as a dependency
    implementation ('com.onedrive.sdk:onedrive-sdk-android:1.3+') {
        transitive = false
    }

    // Include the gson dependency
    implementation ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1')

    // Include supported authentication methods for your application
    implementation ('com.microsoft.services.msa:msa-auth:0.8.+')
    implementation ('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.1.+')
}
```

Put all together, your gradle file will look like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.onedrivesdkapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Include the sdk as a dependency
    implementation ('com.onedrive.sdk:onedrive-sdk-android:1.3+') {
        transitive = false
    }

    // Include the gson dependency
    implementation ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1')

    // Include supported authentication methods for your application
    implementation ('com.microsoft.services.msa:msa-auth:0.8.+')
    implementation ('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.1.+')
}
```

Comment: That fixed the error, thanks.  Is there an alternative library I can use for accessing & editing OneDrive files that IS currently supported?

Comment: I can't help you for the question but you can use this library as long as you have no problem with it.